# What could be causing these spurious 'The name does not exist in the current context' in the debugger?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I am getting random failures of some variables to be readable by the VS debugger datatips, watch and immediate e.g.

[image]

The variables definitely do exist - and trace output shows them working fine. There seems no pattern to the occurences. Sometimes an edit to earlier lines can cause an instance to appear or disappear. The project did not suffer from this until recently, but there have been no major changes to it at this time - just growth in the source files. Debug Optimisation is off. FWIW this app is Winforms not ASP.

Can anyone suggest cause, workaround and ideally, fix? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code from the .cs file please?

Comment: Did you add any VS extensions recently?

Comment: I've read elsewhere that VS is imperfect in doing the job of displaying variables at runtime. It should not be, however, sporadic, but stable and predictable in this regard.

Comment: @Rupert, Sorry no - it is company confidential. But if you can imagine anything elsewhere in the file that could cause this local failure (I can't), please do say.

Comment: @adrift, no I didn't. Thanks for the thought.